# What should i do if write(2) fail?

Tags: c, error-handling

Looking at man 2 write:

```
"On error, -1 is returned, and errno is set appropriately."
```

But if write(2) just fail, it makes nonsense to write an error message right after...
maybe i should write an error message on stderr or maybe just exit() on the first write error?

What do you think?

Comment: That depends on your application's logic. Is a write error recoverable? If not, you might want to immediately call `perror()` followed by `abort()`. Remember all writes to a filesystem can potentially fail with `ENOSPC`, there is no such thing as a "safe" write in that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a typical command line program, error messages should *always* be written to `stderr`, that's what it's for.

Answer (score 3):

`write` can fail on a fd and not on another one. So it makes sense to report on stderr why writing on a socket has failed.